# Page with anchor to form automatically scrolls down to that anchor on page load. How do I stop this?

Tags: magento2

I have a form towards the bottom of this page (http://ibixusa.com/find-a-distributor#distributor-form) - for some reason when the page loads it reads this anchor link and takes you down to the form automatically. I only want the anchor link to work when the text link "complete the form below." is clicked (not when page loads).

Also, is there a way to get rid of the 20x20 pixel grey square box that appears before the form (not sure where this comes from because there is no image there)

below is the code I have on this page:

```
<p>To ensure your business is the <strong>go-to resource</strong> for <strong>high-quality portable surface blasting and coating equipment</strong>, you need to carry the best products available on the market. <strong>You need IBIX</strong>. <a href="mailto:info@ibixusa.com">Contact us today</a> to find out more about <strong>IBIX's full range of products</strong> and how we can help your customers get the job done right!</p>

<p>If you would like to be connected to an authorized <strong>IBIX Distributor</strong> in your area, please <a href="#distributor-form" title="Complete the Find An IBIX Distributor Form">complete the form below</a>. We will be in touch!</p>

<hr noshade="noshade" size=".2" style="height: .2px; width: 100%; border-width: .5px; border-style: single; border-color: #979797; color: #979797;" width="100%" />

<h4>Markets We Cover</h4>

<hr noshade="noshade" size=".2" style="height: .2px; width: 100%; border-width: .5px; border-style: single; border-color: #979797; color: #979797;" width="100%" />

<p><img alt="Markets IBIX Serves - Find a Distributor" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/ibixusa-images/market_serv.png"}}" /></p>

<h4><a name="distributor-form" style="color: #ffffff;">Find A Distributor</a></h4>

<hr noshade="noshade" size=".2" style="height: .2px; width: 100%; border-width: .5px; border-style: single; border-color: #979797; color: #979797;" width="100%" />

{{block type="formbuilder/frontend_form" name="frontend_form" form_id="4" template="formbuilder/form.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default purpose of the anchor link is to jump to the selected area. You can give link without anchor and it will work.

Or you are to check if the anchor part exists in the URL and remove it:

```
// save anchor value for later use, if needed
var form_hash = window.location.hash;
// delete anchor
window.location.hash = "";
```

But this line should be executed before the window load event is fired.